# How to fold a view from 2 3D cameras in Unity?

Tags: unity, 3d, camera

I need to combine view from 2 or more 3D static cameras. Let's say I have 3 humans standing in line side by side.

- The first camera is viewing the left person and the left half of the middle person.
- The second camera is viewing the person on the right and the right half of the middle person.

Now I need to see the whole middle person.

Any ideas how I can do this?

I don't need to see code or some finished implementation, I just need some ideas, because I can not find anything on this.

Comment: i tried using unity forum, but the community there is not so wide

Comment: Maybe you need to use Camera.Viewport?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create two cameras and create a split-screen-like view:

Left camera has a `ViewportRect Width` of `0.5` and the right camera has a `ViewportRect Width` of `0.5` and `X` of `0.5`. Now they are both visible on the screen.

Depending on what type of camera you are using, you may want to set the cameras next to each other so they have aligned boundaries or overlaps (I don't know completely what you want). But I guess this is a good start.

Comment: thank you,and do you have any advise on what to do when they are not aligned? like how to combine the view from them

Comment: Okay, so I tried to write a script that aligned the frustum using the CalculateFrustumCorners() method on the camera. It worked once, but didn't look that nice. Now I just parented one camera onto the other and rotated the child camera in a way that their frustums align. This works.

But may I ask: What do you want to use it for?

Comment: it is for my bachelor thesis, my task is to combine view from multiple 3D cameras in selected direction and im supposed to do it in unity, but im very new to this so im doing some research on what to do

Comment: Okay, so if it is for research stuff (bachelor is fun!) look at Frustums and how they are calculated, how the matrixes are calculated. Check the Unity Documentation for how you get frustum-data out of your camera.

If you need some literature to read, check out "Game Engine Architecture" by Jason Gregory, especially chapter 10.1.4 but overall the whole section about rendering.